# variable changes when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Here is what I am trying to do with this code below. I am receiving the position of an enemy every six frames from the server.

The client-side enemies are stored in an array (called enemies)as objects and these enemy objects have position vectors as a property (called pos), that has an x and y. There is also another position vector (called previousPos) that stores the second most recent position the enemy was at. I am doing this so I can lerp between these two positions so the game can consume less bandwidth while still being smooth.

data[i].x contains the x position that the server sends out to the client every 6 frames, and I am attempting to set the position of the enemy (with pos) to what the server sent out while keeping the enemy's previous position (with previousPos) so I can lerp between them.

This is the function I run whenever the server sends a message regarding enemy stats:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= enemies.length - 1; i++) {              //iterates through all enemies
testerino++;                                     //used to ensure what iteration this is on
if (data[i].x != undefined || data[i].y != undefined) {
    console.log(enemies[i].pos.x,enemies[i].previousPos.x,data[i].x, testerino);
    if (data[i].x != enemies[i].pos.x) enemies[i].previousPos.x = enemies[i].pos.x; //proven they are different
    if (data[i].y != enemies[i].pos.y) enemies[i].previousPos.y = enemies[i].pos.y;
    console.log(enemies[i].pos.x,enemies[i].previousPos.x,data[i].x, testerino);
}
    if (data[i].x != undefined) enemies[i].pos.x = data[i].x;
    if (data[i].x != undefined) console.log(enemies[i].pos.x,enemies[i].previousPos.x,data[i].x, testerino);
    if (data[i].y != undefined) enemies[i].pos.y = data[i].y;
}
```

In the console it returns:
(first number is pos.x, second: previousPos.x, third: what loop we are on)

```
sketch.js:213    587.8102829077167 587.8102829077167 567.8102829082868 225
sketch.js:216    587.8102829077167 587.8102829077167 567.8102829082868 225
sketch.js:219    567.8102829082868 567.8102829082868 567.8102829082868 225
```

Notice that between line 216 and 219 only `enemies[i].pos.x` is assigned to, and **yet somehow `enemies[i].previousPos.x` was also changed as well! Even though I never assigned anything to it!**

Any ideas to what may have went wrong?

Comment: I would guess that there is a line like `data[i].previousPos = data[i].pos` in your code. So please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thats impossible, look at my example, between line 216 and 219 only .pos is assigned to, and yet somehow previousPos changed too

Comment: looking back at this, I see you mean that you mean outside of the shown code that previousPos was made a reference to pos. And yes, that was correct. At the time I didn't know referencing was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier in the code I did indeed do:

```
this.previousPos = this.pos;
```

within the constructor of the enemy function, not knowing that javascript has something called referencing. This means that previousPos was used as a nickname for position, so all changes to pos happenned to previousPos too, as they were the same variable. The library I used had a vector copy method (now i know why its there...) and I think I replaced that code with:

```
this.previousPos = this.pos.copy()
```

as to ensure that previousPos was made into a clone, and not a nickname to the same variable as assignment through the equals sign would've done.